# Função SQL que se aplique a cada linha da coluna

Tags: sql

Trabalhamos com várias tabelas que contém um campo de data, por vezes precisamos separar a string da data em 3 colunas (dia/mês/ano).
Fiz uma função onde se passa a string de data e ele retorna essas 3 colunas, mas como faço para retornar-las dentro de outra Query?

exemplo:

```
select *, separadata(REP_DATA_INICIO) from intranet_reportmensal
```

A função se aplicaria a cada linha dessa query.

a função é essa

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[separadata](@data varchar(10))
 returns TABLE 
 AS RETURN SELECT Parsename(Replace(@data, '/', '.'), 3) as DIA, Parsename(Replace(@data, '/', '.'), 2) as MES, Parsename(Replace(@data, '/', '.'), 1)  as ANO
```

Comment: MS SQL Server? Parece que sim mas é bom adicionar a tag do banco de dados.

Comment: Se não me engano, você pode fazer JOIN com o retorno da função (que retorna tabela) no SQL Server. Mas a solução do @ramaral me parece mais sensata nesse caso específico.

Comment: @bfavaretto Dá pra fazer JOIN com uma função que retorne TABLE. Só que esta pede um parâmetro que é uma coluna da tabela principal do SELECT. Fiquei curioso em saber como fazer isso... De qualquer modo, provavelmente não é uma otimização que valha a pena - não dá tanto trabalho assim usar as funções de data.

Comment: @Caffé Acho que não teria problema passar a coluna da tabela principal e ao mesmo tempo fazer o JOIN. E concordo totalmente com você, para separar a data é melhor usar DATEPART mesmo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tentei e não consegui. Vê lá se você consegue e posta aí por favor: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b287d/10/0

Comment: @bfavaretto Hmm encontrei :-) Vou postar aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Microsoft SQL Server, você pode fazer JOIN com o resultado de uma função cujo retorno seja do tipo `TABLE` (como a sua).

Sugiro trabalhar com tipo e funções específicas de data, como recomendado pelo @ramaral. A função ficaria assim:

```
create FUNCTION dbo.separadata(@data datetime)
 returns TABLE 
 AS RETURN 
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,@data) AS ano,
DATEPART(mm,@data) AS mes,
DATEPART(dd,@data) AS dia
```

E para cosumi-la:

```
select * from Tabela
cross apply separadata(Tabela.data)
```

Veja funcionando: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b287d/14/0

<sub>"Cross apply" créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/699362/1274092</sub>

Comment: Boa. Eu tentei mas bati na trave :)

Comment: A minha resposta resolve mas esta responde diretamente à pergunta!

Answer (score 5):

**SQL SERVER**

Utilize a função ***DATEPART()***

Se o campo *Date* da sua tabela for `minhaData` pode utilizar um SELECT deste tipo para separar essa data em dia/mês/ano.:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,minhaData) AS ano,
       DATEPART(mm,minhaData) AS mes,
       DATEPART(dd,minhaData) AS dia
FROM minhaTabela
```

A função ***DATEPART(datePart, date)*** recebe dois parâmetros:

- *datepart* - indica a parte da data a extrair e pode ser uma das seguinte opções: **ano**: yyyy,yy **mês**: mm,m **dia**: dd,d ([mais opções](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp))
- *date* - uma expressão que represente uma tipo *Date*: **time**, **date**, **smalldatetime**, **datetime**, **datetime2**, ou **datetimeoffset**, pode ser uma coluna de uma tabela, uma variável ou uma string.

---

**MySQL**

Utilize as funções ***YEAR(date)***, ***MONTH(date)*** e ***DAY(date)***

```
SELECT YEAR(minhaData) AS ano,
       MONTH(minhaData) AS mes,
       DAY(minhaData) AS dia
FROM minhaTabela
```